# Unexpected '=' error when assigning a custom option with paste

Tags: r

The option name created with `paste` does not work when I try to set custom options. What might be the cause of it?

```
# --- this works fine
options("a.1" = Sys.Date())
getOption("a.1")
# --- an error...
options(paste("a", 1, sep=".") = Sys.Date())
#> Error: <text>:5:32: unexpected '='
#> 4: # Error...
#> 5: options(paste("a", 1, sep=".") =
#>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do by calling that command?

Comment: I have a set of `options` that are going to be used in a package. There are many and I want to have a possibility to set names on the fly, such as in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
options(setNames(list(Sys.Date()), paste0("a.", 1)))
getOption("a.1")
#[1] "2018-06-03"
```